# Gradle task to copy dependent jars to a folder along with group name

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I already know to copy dependent jars into a folder:

```
task copyJARsToLib(type: Copy) {    
    from configurations.default
    into 'Applicationlib'
}
```

After running this task all the dependent jars get copied into `Applicationlib` folder, the name of the jar is `{artifactName-version.jar}` for eg. for `implementation("org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.2.2")` jar name becomes `poi-ooxml-5.2.2.jar`.

What I want is after copying jar name should also have group name like: `group.name_version.jar` for eg. `org.apache.poi.poi-ooxml-5.2.2.jar`

I tried

```
configurations.default.each {
          
}
```

But this iterator has `File` object hence only has jar file name and not group name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are certainly other ways to achieve this, but the following will work fine, if your project has only [module dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html#sub:module_dependencies) (else you might need to adapt a bit)

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.2.2")
}
task copyDependenciesWithGroup {
    doLast {
        configurations.default.resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts.forEach{ ResolvedArtifact artifact ->
            project.copy {
                from artifact.file
                into 'ApplicationlibWithGroup'
                rename { String fileName ->
                    "${artifact.moduleVersion.id.group}.$fileName"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will copy the folling jars in `ApplicationlibWithGroup` directory:

```
$ ls -l ApplicationlibWithGroup/
 com.github.virtuald.curvesapi-1.07.jar
 com.zaxxer.SparseBitSet-1.2.jar
 commons-codec.commons-codec-1.15.jar
 commons-io.commons-io-2.11.0.jar
 org.apache.commons.commons-collections4-4.4.jar
 org.apache.commons.commons-compress-1.21.jar
 org.apache.commons.commons-math3-3.6.1.jar
 org.apache.logging.log4j.log4j-api-2.17.2.jar
 org.apache.poi.poi-5.2.2.jar
 org.apache.poi.poi-ooxml-5.2.2.jar
 org.apache.poi.poi-ooxml-lite-5.2.2.jar
 org.apache.xmlbeans.xmlbeans-5.0.3.jar
```